# From MongoDB into ElasticSearch: Converting meta field of _id

Tags: elasticsearch, pymongo

I'm using pymongo to insert a document from MongoDB into Elasticsearch, and getting an error below.  The problem looks like the '_id'.  How can I convert the "_id" to "id" before inserting it into ElasticSearch?

Error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 
u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'Field [_id] is a metadata field and 
cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request 
parameters.')
```

Code:

```
for doc in documents1.find():
   doc_sanitized = json.loads(json_util.dumps(doc))
   es.index(index='index-name', doc_type='intel', id=i, body=doc_sanitized)
```

Comment: You'll have to remove all fields starting with a `_` (those are reserved) from the `doc_sanitized` or change the fields to a different name.

Comment: Any recommendation on how to remove `_id` or change it?  I'm struggling to find a solution.

Comment: Never mind, found a solution.  I converted the mongo document to a string, ran string replace, and converted it back to a dict.  Then inserted it in and it works.

Comment: I assume this is a dictionary, so `doc_sanitized.pop('_id', None)` should to the job